# What determines the use of other threads besides the main thread when working with asynchronous tasks (in Unity3D)?

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, asynchronous, task

I was playing around with async tasks in Unity when I noticed some behavior I couldn't explain. While printing out some values on the console to see what was going on, I noticed something about the thread IDs of the various scenarios I was playing around with.
The code below includes the following:

- Two tests within a "fire and forget" async void to get everything going
- A task awaiting another task (a small delay)
- And a few debug logs to monitor the thread IDs of each started task

**TEST 1** within the Start method just awaits the SimpleTask and gives the following output:

- Task started on thread: 1
- SimpleTask before delay on thread: 1
- SimpleDelay on thread: 1
- SimpleTask after delay on thread: 1

**TEST 2** on the other hand leads to this:

- Task started on thread: 1
- SimpleTask before delay on thread: 25
- SimpleDelay on thread: 25
- SimpleTask after delay on thread: 26

**Why does the second test result in the use of other threads?**
My understanding of this line is that it simply wraps the first test in an extra layer of an async task. I know there's no point in doing that, but I can't figure out why it completely changes the results of the initial test. It's not like the first test is running synchronously. I would like to understand what is going on here, the more explanation the better.

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UnityEngine;

public class TestAsyncTask : MonoBehaviour
{

    private async void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log($"Task started on thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");

        // TEST 1
        await SimpleTaskAsync();

        // TEST 2
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => await SimpleTaskAsync());
    }

    private async Task SimpleTaskAsync()
    {
        Debug.Log($"SimpleTask before delay on thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        await SimpleDelayAsync();
        Debug.Log($"SimpleTask after delay on thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
    }

    private async Task SimpleDelayAsync()
    {
        Debug.Log($"SimpleDelay on thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

Additional specs (I doubt they matter but here are they anyway):

- Unity version 2021.3.11f1
- API compatibility level: .NET Framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`await` by default will capture the current context (`SynchronizationContext` or `TaskScheduler`) and will resume executing the `async` method in that context; if there is no context, then they will run on a thread pool thread. I recommend you read my [`async` intro](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) which goes into more detail.

In this case, I assume the code is executed within a UI context (on the UI thread). UI frameworks provide a `SynchronizationContext` so that code after the `await` resumes on the UI thread.

> My understanding of this line is that it simply wraps the first test in an extra layer of an async task.

The reason the second code *doesn't* use the UI thread is because of the `StartNew` (which, as I describe on my blog, is [dangerous](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html); use `Task.Run` instead). `Task.Run` always executes its delegate on a thread pool thread, and `StartNew` (in this case) does, too. Thread pool threads do not have any context for `await` to capture, so the code after the `await` runs on any available thread pool thread.

Comment: Your blog post was very helpful, thanks for the quick reply! After reading the part about context, I played around a bit more with the test script I posted above and I have two follow-up questions:
1) Given the new information, I changed the first test `await SimpleTaskAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);` expecting it to run on different threads. It didn't. It still ran everything on the main thread.
2) Wouldn't `await Task.Run(() => SimpleTaskAsync().ConfigureAwait(false));` add another layer of task around `SimpleTaskAsync()` compared to just `await SimpleTaskAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);`?

Comment: 1) `await SimpleTaskAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)` is essentially the same as `var task = SimpleTaskAsync(); var configuredTask = task.ConfigureAwait(false); await configuredTask;` - i.e., the `ConfigureAwait(false)` is called *after* `SimpleTaskAsync()`, so it doesn't change the context captured in `SimpleTaskAsync`.
2) `Task.Run` executes the delegate on a thread pool thread. It does introduce another task, yes, but that's more of a side effect.

Comment: After reading additional docs/blog posts, I think I have a better understanding of `ConfigureAwait` and why/when to use it. Especially in the context of deadlocks. My last remaining question would be the following:
Since `ConfigureAwait(false)` keeps the context alive for the task it is called on, what would be the best way to run everything on the thread pool thread from the beginning? Using the example code from above: `await Task.Run(() => SimpleTaskAsync());` ?

Comment: @ge.go: Yes; of you want to run code on a thread pool thread, the best way in most cases is `Task.Run`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed responses! Both your comments and your blog have been very helpful. I consider my original question closed now. I will still buy your book though ;)